# Non trivial commutant implies proper projection

Tags: representation-theory, hilbert-spaces, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I've been reading Kenneth Davidson's book on C*-Algebras and found the following assertion in the section of representation of C*-algebras:
"Given a C*-algebra $\mathfrak{A}$ and a representation $\pi$ on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, if $\pi(\mathfrak{A})'$ (the commutator of $\pi(\mathfrak{A}))$ isn't equal to $\mathbb{C}I$ then there exists a proper projection in $\pi(\mathfrak{A})'$."
He states that it's due to a theorem relating convex hull of set of projections but I didn't understood well that method. In other book I saw that it could be obtained using the polar decomposition and constructing the projection that way, I just don't know why it should be proper. Basically I'd like to know why there's an operator $T\in \pi(\mathfrak{A})$ such that $\overline{T(\mathcal{H})}\lneq \mathcal{H}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C$^*$-algebra $\pi(\mathfrak A)'$ is a von Neumann algebra (i.e., it is weak-operator closed). This allows you to perform Borel functional calculus on normal operators. So, take any nontrivial positive operator $T\in\pi(\mathfrak A)'$, and write its spectrum $\sigma(T)=A\cup B$, with $A,B$ disjoint Borel sets. Then $P=1_A(T),Q=1_B(T)$ are nonzero pairwise orthogonal projections in $\pi(\mathfrak A)'$, and so they are nontrivial.

Comment: I haven't studied much about Borel functional calculus, can I just take something like a partition of unity on the spectrum of said positive operator?

Comment: I don't see why. A partition of the unity (in the Real Analysis sense) will not give you projections.

Comment: oh, that's true

Comment: @MartinArgerami What if the spectrum of the nontrival positive operator is a singleton set  ?

Comment: The point is that $\pi(\mathfrak A)'$ is not trivial. That means precisely that there exists positive $T$ with non-singleton spectrum.

Comment: @MartinArgerami If $\sigma(T)=\{0,1\}, A=\{0\}$ and $B=\{1\}$, then the inclusion map $z=1_B$,  therefore $T=z(T)=1_B(T)=P, $ and $Q=T-P=0.$

Comment: @C.Ding: No. First, $T$ is already a nontrivial projection, which was the point. Second, $Q=I-T$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Oh, the second is my fault! I just got stuck at why there exists positive operator $T$ with non-singleton spectrum. Now it's clear, if $\sigma(T)=\{\lambda\}$, then $T=z(T)=\lambda(T)=\lambda I$.

Answer (score 1):

The method of "convex hull" is an easy way:

Since $\pi(\mathfrak A)'$ is a von Neumann algebra, it is the closed linear span of its projections. Therefore if all the projections in $\pi(\mathfrak A)'$ are trival, then  $\pi(\mathfrak A)'=\mathbb{C}1.$

Where are you confused?